# Unable to upload directory to hdfs. `/usr/local/tmp/': No such file or directory

Tags: xubuntu, amazon-ec2, hadoop

I'm trying to upload files to a directory i made on HDFS but I'm not able to do so as ubuntu is not able to locate the files on my machine. The directory 'states'(one i'm trying to upload) contains 50 txt files, is in my download folder(path: /home/shradha/Downloads). I'm trying to upload these files in my ec2 hadoop instance in hdfs/states (I have already created hdfs and states). I read somewhere that only files in `tmp` folder can be moved so i moved the directory i want to upload to `hdfs` to `tmp` folder still no luck, I believe it has something to do with the `hduser`.

Below are the commands I tried:

```
hduser@ip-172-31-18-210:~/hadoop-2.7.2$ bin/hadoop fs -put /shradha/Downloads/states /hdfs/states
put: `/shradha/Downloads/states': No such file or directory

hduser@ip-172-31-18-210:~/hadoop-2.7.2$ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /usr/local/tmp/states /hdfs/states
copyFromLocal: `/usr/local/tmp/states': No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Absolute path vs relative path in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)

Answer (score 1):

You say your local files are under (path: /home/shradha/Downloads) but you are trying to upload /shradha/Downloads.

check local directory existence:

```
ls -al /home/shradha/Downloads/states
```

if you can list files you are good to go:

```
bin/hadoop fs -put /home/shradha/Downloads/states /hdfs/states
```